# the development server returned response error code: 500

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

I tried to do something with google-trends-api in React Native.
I load the module following the instruction in the description:
    const googleTrends = require('google-trends-api');
after installing google-trends-api on npm.
but when I start my app, the following issue comes up:

[image]

I reinstalled it again but it didn't help.

Comment: `npm install https`

Comment: Try resetting the bundler cache: `react-native start --reset-cache`

Comment: Maybe linking the package with react-native link. Than you have to restart the development server.

Comment: I installed https on npm but it was same.
and I couldn't do 'react-native start --reset-cashe' on CLI.
the console said it's not a runnable program or file.

Comment: My project is installed by create-react-native-app. is it the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `google-trends-api` is using `https` library, however it is not added to the `package.json` file. You should try the following;

1. Run `npm install --save https` on your own project and see if you are getting the same error. If not, perfect. If you do;
2. Go into the `google-trends-api` in your `node_modules` and try the same thing. If this solves your problem however, you should note that it is only a local solution and you should fork the repository, update its dependencies and submit a pull request.